# Convert varchar with timezone to a timestamp? (snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I convert the following varchar to a timestamp in snowflake?

`2020-10-02 12:52:01 UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

SELECT
try_to_timestamp_ntz ('2020-10-02 12:52:01 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS UTC')
FROM
DUAL;

Comment: So the column contains the string UTC at the end and thus returns null.  I suppose I can chop off the UTC part of it, but was hoping there was another way?

Comment: Include UTC in the spec:  SELECT
    try_to_timestamp_ntz ('2020-10-02 12:52:01 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS UTC')
FROM
    DUAL;

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the UTC designation.

Comment: doesn't this work too? `left('2020-10-02 12:52:01 UTC', 20)`

and it is a bit more future proof, in the event that the UTC is in a different timezone (e.g. EST, PST)

Comment: I don't see that future proofing at all - if you have designations for the TZ, and are stripping them off, you're effectively eliminating the offsets that are associated with those times.  You might be better off parsing out the TZ designation, and putting that in the string used for the conversion.

Comment: Ah great point! Parsing the timestamp to a separate column makes sense!

To do the conversion, is the best route a case when statement as follows?

```case when timezone = 'UTC'  then created_at
when timezone = 'ETC' then convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', created_at::timestamp_ntz)::date```

Comment: As the use case wasn't presented with this post, I can't really say what the best route may be - are these dates already present in your tables or are you ingesting data from a 3rd party to store in data lake, etc.   The original question was how do you convert a varchar to a timestamp in Snowflake.  That's been addressed here.  If the follow on is how to deal with multiple TZs and process offsets, that's another Ted Talk :-)